# Login_redirect hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication, hook

I have already used this hook in the same way described below, What could be going wrong?

```
class my_plugin {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        var_dump(__LINE__); // run 
        add_filter('login_redirect', array($this, 'login_redirect'));
    }

    function login_redirect()
    {
        var_dump(__LINE__); // not run
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1**

This `hook` run after successfully login processes. As I said I have used this hook in another plugins. The question is What could cause this malfunction?

Comment: Going to have to see more code I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it.

**For the record:**

It is sure that could helps someone else. Indeed time ago I suffered a problem triggered by the same reason: `is_admin()` incorrect use:

My starter code is:

```
if (is_admin())
{
    // block 1
    // 
    // run admin classes
    // including my_plugin class
    // that includes login_redirect hook // WRONG!
}
else
{
    // block 2
    // 
    // run frontend classes
}
```

`login_redirect` hook does not run inside admin pages (`is_admin()` condition)

**Solution**: move login_redirect hook to frontend block

Comment: Well would you look at that, the problem lied outside of the code you initially provided. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: @jeremy1026 man take it easy. I supposed that you will said that!!! LOL I can't put here all WP code, right? That's why I told you that ask for more code when you know what I am talking about (you have 0 WP tags in your profile).

Comment: @jeremy1026  And please revoke downvote, OK? there is no reason for it. This question will be very useful for other WP coders. I am very sure of that. Peace...

Comment: Downvote isn't from me. But you'd have to think that if your code isn't being called, it'd be a good idea to post up what you expect should be calling it.